# What are the differences between C++ and C# primitive data types?

Tags: c#, c++, types, primitive-types

I am trying to figure out the differences between C++ and C# data types. I know C# and java differ because data types are stored as objects in C# instead of having the core class library providing a wrapper class to represent the data types as a Java object. However I can't find much on the differences of C# and C++ data types...

Comment: Your title has *primitive* but your main question doesn't.  If you edit to clearly ask only about primitives (or better yet, only arithmetic types), it would no longer be too broad.

Comment: BTW, the C# specification doesn't use the phrase "primitive type(s)", although .NET does.  C# talks about *simple types*, which includes `System.Decimal` which is definitely not equivalent to any C++ primitive.

Comment: There isn't any difference.  A very good way to get a C# programmer **very** upset is to point out that *int* is a keyword in that language.  That maps to System.Int32 today, but, you know, maybe not some day in the future.

Answer (score 4):

The difference you describe is wrong. Java, C# and C++ all treat the primitives as basic objects. C and C++, being low-level languages, keep them that way - they are unique to the compiler as primitives.

In Java, there exist thin wrappers, such as [`java.lang.Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) which is a class containing a single `int` member variable.

C# can implicitly treat a primitive as an object, and will on the fly convert for example an `int` to a `System.Int32` as required by various situations. The process is called [Boxing and Unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx), of which the first is implicit and the second is explicit. For further reference see the linked article.

Comment: `System.Int32`, by the way.  Also, C# has a lot of builtin types that are not builtin in C++.

Comment: Fixed, thanks, haven't done a lot of C# in the past few years.

Comment: an `int` _is_ a `System.Int32`  There is no boxing involved because there is no conversion.  Only when converted to an `object` is it boxed.

Comment: @DStanley: Or to an interface.  But you're right that `System.Int32` is the unboxed form, like the `int` keyword and unlike `java.lang.Integer`

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply, C#'s primitive types like `int` `bool`, `short` etc... are organized as structures,  in contrary with C++ primitive types which are not structures.

For example, in the C# on the `int` primitive type itself you can call some methods (for example you can call methods `Parse` or `Equals`). This is also true for the `bool` primitive type.

To go even further, `Int32` and `int` are totally the same types in the C#, as well as `bool` and `Boolean` are. So the `int`, `bool`, `short` etc... are keywords in the C# which are actually masking the following structures `Int32`, `Boolean`, `Int16`. You can try it by calling:

```
int a=int.MaxValue;
Int32 b = a;
```

In the first line we are creating variable `a` which type is `int`. The value of the variable `a` is set to the `int.MaxValue` which is actually constant defined in the type `int` or to be more precisely `Int32`.

On the second line value of the variable b becomes the value of the variable a. This 
confirms that `a` and `b` are the variables of the same type, otherwise, an error would occur.

At the other hand, in the C++, primitive types are not organized as structures, so you can't call any method on the primitive type or the primitive type instance. These are also called compiler primitives.

Comment: You can even write `a.ToString()`.  But `string` is not a primitive type.